# Преобразовать в SCSS

Tags: scss

Что нужно для преобразования этого кода из CSS в SCSS, использовать mixin или extend?

```css
main > nav, main > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Подойдет ли такой вариант и считается ли он правильным в данном случае?

```css
@mixin default {
  display: inline-block;
}
  
main > nav {
  @include default;
}
  
main > div {
  @include default;
}
```

Comment: Есть онлайн сервисы для такого рода операций, в том числе [css 2 scss](http://sebastianpontow.de/css2compass/)

Comment: @Deonis спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SCSS будет это записано как:

```
//Вариант 1
main{
  & > nav, & > div{
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

//Вариант 2
@mixin inline-block(){
  display: inline-block;
}

main{

  & > nav{
    @include inline-block;
  }

  & > nav{
    @include inline-block;
  }
}

//Вариант 3
main{
  & > nav, & > div{
    @include inline-block;
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хорошая книга по SCSS - это [Sass for Web Designers by Dan Cederholm](https://ru.scribd.com/document/271241999/Sass-for-Web-Designers-by-Dan-Cederholm)

Comment: Просто у нас получается что селекторы через запятую, а сделать иначе можно как то?

Comment: @GlebPristupa Я написал код в пределах того, что вижу в твоем вопроcе) Если приведешь пример свое кода и укажешь где проблема - я расширю свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо за книгу, я написал в ответе код, верно ли так?

Comment: @GlebPristupa ответ лучше удалить и дополнить свой код в вопросе. Что именно хотелось бы видеть: HTML + CSS/SCSS, чтобы понятнее было

Comment: а `&` в данном случае зачем?

Comment: @GlebPristupa, а что не так с селекторами через запятую?

Comment: @Grundy Да вроде все нормально с запятыми, но мне казалось, что как раз таки в препроцессорах необходимо избегать их

Comment: @GlebPristupa увы, без селекторов иногда не обойтись. Допустим, при наводке одного блока, ты хотел бы, чтобы ПАРАЛЛЕЛЬНЫЙ блок изменялся, то ты напишешь (как варик) `.first:hover ~ .second{}`

Comment: @Antonio112009 спасибо за развернутый ответ

Comment: @GlebPristupa Последнее... Изучи Flexbox. Уверен, тебе понравится) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @GlebPristupa пример flexbox'ов https://codepen.io/antonio112009/pen/YgzmJE

Comment: @Antonio112009 уже знаком с Flexbox, однако мне больше понравились Grid. Но я стараюсь чередовать, что бы укреплять знания